# How to read CSV File into Vector Store

Tags: python, nlp, language-model, csv

I have a CSV file, and I am using langchain to read it into the vector store FAISS. My question is, since I have a CSV file, is RecursiveTextSplitter required? Put differently, consider the following codes

```
# Code A ------------------------------
myData = CSVLoader(file_path=myCSVFile")
finalData = myData.load()

text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
    chunk_size=100,
    chunk_overlap = 10,
    length_function = len,
)

theFile = text_splitter.transform_documents(finalData)

vector_store = FAISS.from_documents(theFile, embedder)
```

Compare to following code:

```
# Code B ------------------------------
myData = CSVLoader(file_path=myCSVFile")
finalData = myData.load()

vector_store = FAISS.from_documents(finalData, embedder)
```

Is code A correct or coe B?